# NEGOTIATE authentication error: (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)) - Microsoft SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to download some data in the form of `Json` from a `SharePoint` API. I was able to do it using `WGET` and I am trying to do the same thing with a Java program. Below is my code:

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST,AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new NTCredentials("username","password",null,"sharepoint2.domain.com"));

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build();

try {
    HttpGet jsonGet = new HttpGet("URL");      
    jsonGet.setHeader("Accept","Application/json;odata=verbose");
        HttpResponse json = httpClient.execute(jsonGet);
        System.out.println(json.toString());
        System.out.println(json.getStatusLine());
        System.out.println(json.getEntity().toString());
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))
HttpResponseProxy{HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5, SPRequestGuid: 8dd6489e-f91e-1018-e731-4711c8a5147c, request-id: 8dd6489e-f91e-1018-e731-4711c8a5147c, SPRequestDuration: 23, SPIisLatency: 0, WWW-Authenticate: NTLM, WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4859, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly, Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 15:43:03 GMT, Content-Length: 0]
```

I have limited knowledge regarding `kerberos` and don't understand what the error means. I am running the java program using the same kerberos ticket I used for `WGET`. It works for `WGET` but not sure why it is throwing an error with the Java program.

Here's the output of my WGET command:

```
$wget --user username --password password --header='Accept: application/json;odata=verbose' "URL"
--2018-02-09 10:20:55--  'URL'
Resolving sharepoint2.domain.com... xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Connecting to sharepoint2.domain.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to sharepoint2.domain.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to sharepoint2.domain.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: “items?$top=1000.7”
```

From the output, I see that it tries to authorize and fails twice, then uses an existing connection. I am not sure why that happens.

So, how do I get my java program working to do the same thing as `wget`? Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.